# Simple CMOS Analog Square-Rooting and Squaring Circuits

Tags: transistors, mosfet

In Fig 1 of [Simple CMOS Analog Square-Rooting and Squaring Circuits](https://sci-hub.tw/https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/129463) , Why would the lower transistor Q1 guaranteed to be in triode operating region ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because its Vsourcedrain is nearly zero. That is triode region.

Given both FETs have the same gate voltage, the Vgs of the upper FET consumes most of the available drain voltage or the upper FET will not be diode connected.

Comment: wait, why its Vsourcedrain is nearly zero ?

Comment: How exactly do the Vgs of both mosfets affect Vds1 ?